# Redactor upload image and file does not work

Tags: redactor, upload, craft-features

I succeeded to add the image and file upload buttons to my rich text redactor field with the fileupload param in the json config file.

[image: redactor toolbar]

`{
    buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','video','table','file'],
    plugins: ['fullscreen','video','table',''],
    toolbarFixed: true,
    fileUpload: 'fichiers/'
}`

But it does not work : when I drap and drop a file or an image it shows the top bar indicating upload in progress but it finish without anything inserted in my field.

Comment: You do not need to modify the redactor config to get image inserting from your assets into a rich text field. Have you set up your asset source correctly? Can you see assets a source in your assets tab?

Comment: Yes I got my assets ressources defined but I do understand in CRAFT CMS a clear link between redactor and the assets. It is not so clear for me...

Answer (score 1):

Craft's default Redactor implementation comes with image selection and uploading out-of-the-box that ties to its [Assets sources](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets).

If you click this button:

[image]

You'll get a modal where you can select already uploaded Assets or upload new ones.

[image]

Comment: Yes this works but if I drag and drog it does not work. I see the upload in progress bar but no image show up at the end. Also when I click on FILE UPLOAD button and choose a file to upload it fails.

Comment: You can check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for `[error]` to see if there is any underlying error message getting logged.

Comment: Hi Brad, sorry I was MIA for 1 month. So to continue this subject I am checking the log but I got 1600 error new lines suddenly appearing, I am not sure what to check.  Do you have an example of clear path for the parameter : fileUpload: '?'.

Comment: Also second subject concerning the file upload in redactor, I am trying to use the ADD FILE button but it does add not my file at all.